# Moving Object/Bitmap in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, object, move

I haven't been able to find much code/tutorials on Moving an object with Threads in Java for Android. I would like some help or code on moving the X and Y position with Threads in Java for Android.

Comment: Can you rephrase or elaborate on your question please? It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main hurdle you are facing is that you are thinking of the location of drawing the bitmap being somehow tied to the bitmap itself. You need to track them separately. int draw_x and int draw_y and update those values using your thread or a timer or whatever means you want. Then, in the onDraw method of your view, you want to canvas.translate to the position draw_x,draw_y and then draw your bitmap.

You don't want to "move the bitmap", you want to alter the translation of the canvas when the bitmap is drawn.

Comment: Thank you very much that has fixed the problem.